# Detection failed: Resource not found

Tags: java, android, azure, azure-cognitive-services

I am using Azure Cognitive Service Face to develop an Android App to detect faces.

I am trying to reproduce the result in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/tutorials/faceapiinjavaforandroidtutorial

I am coding with Java in Android Studio.

I am using a picture from the drawable folder and convert it to bitmap using:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.test_image);
```

I made sure that the bitmap is working properly by showing it in another imageView `imgV.setImageBitmap(bitmap);` The image is shown properly in the imageView.

Then I call `detectAndFrame(bitmap)`.

In the line `Face[] result = faceServiceClient.detect(params[0],true,false,null);`

I got the exception *Resource not found*.

I am wondering where the problem is. 
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. It turns out to be the endpoint URL issue.

For JAVA in Android Studio, use:
https://LOCATION_SPECIFIED_WHEN_CREATING_THE_RESOURCE.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/

For example, if you chose west US 2 when generating the face resource, use the endpoint as:

https://westus2.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/

If a wrong endpoint is given, it is possible that you will get an exception called "Resource not found" when calling a function from the client.

Also, do not forget to add the closing slash in the endpoint address!

Hope that helps.